# :detailed_logger is not registered on Faraday::Response

Tags: faraday

I am trying to use faraday-detailed_logger gem https://github.com/envylabs/faraday-detailed_logger like below

```
connection = Faraday.new(:url => endpoint) do |c|
        c.use Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded
        c.response :detailed_logger , logger
        c.use Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp
     end
```

I am getting below error while making a faraday call after that

```
Faraday::Error
:detailed_logger is not registered on Faraday::Response
```

Does any one know what additional needs to be done here to so that I can use the gem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try requiring `detailed_logger` first.

```
require 'faraday'
require 'faraday/detailed_logger'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gem [faraday-conductivity](https://github.com/yourkarma/faraday-conductivity#extended-logging) for faraday logging and it works

```
connection = Faraday.new(url: "http://widgets.yourapp.com") do |faraday|
  faraday.use :extended_logging, logger: Rails.logger
end
```